# upload images from URL to easy_thumbnails field

Tags: django, image, urllib2, django-models

I want to upload many images from URLs while I create objects with a script.

```
#models.py
class Widget(TimeStampedModel):    
        name = CharField ... etc, etc
        pic = ThumbnailerImageField(_('Widget Pic'), 
        upload_to='widget/pic/', 
        help_text = _('Please submit your picture here.'),
        null=True, blank=True)
```

so I thought of using the save method in that class to download and save the images.  So my script creates the Widget objects and saves the image url, and then the save method tries to download and save the image.  My save method so far is:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    if self.pic:
        if self.pic.name.startswith( 'http://') and self.pic.name.endswith(('.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.svg')):
            my_temp_pic = open('test.image', 'w')
            my_temp_pic.write(urllib2.urlopen(self.pic.name).read())
            my_temp_pic.close()

            my_temp_pic = open('test.image')

            thumbnailer = get_thumbnailer(my_temp_pic, relative_name = self.slug+'.'+self.pic.name.split('.')[-1])
            self.pic = thumbnailer.get_thumbnail({'size': (200, 0), 'crop': False})
    super(Widget, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've tried to open the file in different ways with .read() or .open() ... but the only way I found (above) feels quite hackish (save some temp file with the image, re-open, then save).  Is there a better way?  I'm I missing a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the temporary file is the only solution I know too. Check this:  http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1890/

So basically you don't need to do hackish like `close()` and `open()` again. You can do:

```
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile

# ... your code here ...

my_temp_pic = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
my_temp_pic.write(urllib2.urlopen(self.pic.name).read())
my_temp_pic.flush()

relative_name = '%s.%s' % (self.slug, self.pic.name.split('.')[-1])
thumbnailer = get_thumbnailer(my_temp_pic, relative_name=relative_name)

# ... your code again ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: didn't know about NamedTemporaryFile and flush(), thanks for letting me know about those tools.